# mat-card - How to keep checkbox status when using pagination?

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination

I have the following code to create `mat-cards` based on Http response:

```
            <div">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let card of obs$ | async; let i = index;" formArrayName="entities">
                    <div>
                        <mat-card>
                            <mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-title>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{card.name}}"
                                           [value]="card.id" (change)="onCheck($event, card.id)"> {{card.displayName}}
                                </mat-card-title>
                            </mat-card-header>
                            <mat-card-content>
                                <div>Username: {{card.name}}</div>
                                <div>Email: {{card.email}}</div>
                            </mat-card-content>
                        </mat-card>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            ...
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

All works fine, except the checkbox status when I use the pagination. Means if I select a checkbox and navigate to next list using pagination and I navigate back, then the previously selected checkbox is not selected any more. I have been searching and tried couple of ideas, but none of them did work. Also `(page)="pageEvent = $event"` in the `paginator` tag didn't fix the issue. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried to store the values in a service?

Comment: No. I don't want to use a service for that. It should and can be implemented in the component itself. Must work like mat-table actually.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox type input's checked status is depends on the input attribute `checked`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

So you may do something like `[checked]=card.isChecked`.

Then in your card array, you may add a property called `isChecked` on every item, so the interface of the card will be something like this:

```
const card: Card[];

interface Card {
    //... existing property
    isChecked: boolean;
}

// in html change this following 
(change)=onCheck($event, card)

// in ts file change the onCheck function
onCheck(event, card) {
    card.isChecked = event.target.value;
}
```

Then, every card checked status can be tracked by `isChecked` property unless the web page is refreshed.

Hope that's help. Please let me know if the information I shared is helpful to you, I am still learning too.